# DHCP Pool Range / IP-Camera Setup

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp, ip-camera

Lately I have been trying to set up a IP-Camera for friends wirelessly.

I realized on their router its DHCP pool range is from 192.169.2.100 - 192.168.2.200.

But when I changed the IP address of the IP-Camera to (static) ex. 192.168.2.5 it will still work and be connected for a few hours. I wonder why this is still working because it is obviously out of the range of what their DCHP Pool allows.

Hours later the IP-Camera would no longer be connected / discovered by the router. But it baffles me that it could be connected in the first place with IP being out of range.

I am not using Windows Networking Tab to configure the static IP Address for the IP-Camera, because the installation CD claims to do that without. Have not been successful setting it up in their place, although I managed to do so at my home with their camera.

Their router is on IP 192.168.2.2, by the way.

Any help / pointer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP ranges are just the Dynamically allocated ranges. My bet is that their network is Using `192.168.2.1/24` addressing. or The network `192.168.2.0` with a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0` (same thing just two ways of saying it)   So, when you give them an address of `.2.5` It is STILL probably a valid address, just statically allocated. My Guess (cant say anything definite) is that something else is trying to fight with this device for that IP and so neither of them work.

Try turning off the cameras and seeing if anything will respond to those `.2.5` type addresses (statically allocated, not DHCP) maybe they left something else at that address and forgot about it.

Also, if you can give me your subnet mask I can confirm my suspicions about the IP addressing Scheme. The DHCP range of `2.100-2.200` would seem to support it (since it rules out most normal subnets) but confirming never hurts

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, their subnet mask is indeed `255.255.255.0`. It is a router by Deutscher Telekom. Leaving the camera plugged in via LAN works, but per WLAN works as described - connected for a few hours / at times the whole day until evening. Then connection is lost again. I have tried before to use `ipconfig` to check, and besides my laptop and theirs, whose IP addresses lie within `192.169.2.100 - 192.168.2.200`, nothing else is on `2.5`. Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig does the router have a list of clients? or any mention of DHCP leases? It may be possible that the Cameras are not talking to the router much and are being dropped because they arent saying anything. I would recommend to be sure to give each camera a Unique address in the range of `192.168.2.10`-`192.168.2.20` or however many you need. But, be sure they do not stray into your laptops addresses or the `192.168.2.100`-`192.168.2.200` range.

Comment: If the router has mention of clients, perhaps try checking the Table of clients to see if it is disconnecting the cameras from the router side, or if the cameras are stopping the communication. If the cameras are listed after they stop responding, then there is some issue with the camera. If they are not listed, the router may have not seen any communication from them and assumed they diedc

Comment: When it is connected, it can be seen from the list. When it isn't, it is not shown on the list. At my home I was successful in connecting the camera. I have on my router .2.1, with more computers (they have just one laptop) and when I set the camera IP as .2.5 with my other computers on ex: .2.4 or .2.6 etc etc, the camera is connected wirelessly without problem, never dropped. I guess I would pay them a visit and write down all router information for you in next post. Thanks a lot.